# Single SUMIFS and COUNTIFS work, but two SUMIFS and two COUNTIFS do not work

Tags: microsoft-excel-365

I'm exporting data for a manufacturing environment and importing the CSV into Excel. This data refreshes every 5 minutes.

On the first worksheet, I'm able to calculate efficiency % properly (N:N) with a single SUMIFS and a single COUNTIFS. However, when I try to add two SUMIFS and divide by two added COUNTIFS the calculation reports an incorrect result. I should add that there are times when either "HMP20 1" or "GHMP20 1" are not present.

This formula returns the expected result `100.83`:

```
=(SUMIFS('EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!N:N,
         'EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!B:B, "1",
         'EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!C:C, "GHMP20 1")/
 (COUNTIFS('EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!N:N, ">0",
         'EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!B:B, "1",
         'EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!C:C, "GHMP20 1")))
```

This calculation returns an incorrect result: `388.61`:

```
=(SUMIFS('EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!N:N,
         'EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!B:B, "1",
         'EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!C:C,"HMP20 1")+
  SUMIFS('EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!N:N,
         'EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!B:B, "1",
         'EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!C:C, "GHMP20 1")/
 (COUNTIFS('EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!N:N, ">0",
         'EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!B:B, "1",
         'EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!C:C, "HMP20 1")+
  COUNTIFS('EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!N:N, ">0",
         'EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!B:B, "1",
         'EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts'!C:C, "GHMP20 1")))
```

#### Sample Data

**Worksheet:** "EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts"

|  | B | C | D - M | N |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Shift** | **Machine** |  | **EFF %** |  |
| **2** | 1 | GHMP20 1 |  | 101 |  |
| **3** | 1 | GHMP20 1 |  | 98 |  |
| **4** | 1 | HMP20 1 |  | 112 |  |
| **5** | 3 | HMP20 1 |  | 87 |  |
| **6** | 3 | SINTO 7 |  | 92 |  |
| **7** | 3 | GSINTO 7 |  |  |  |

<sub>**Data worksheet: "EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts"**</sub>
[image: Data worksheet: "EP2P Mold Summary All Shifts]

<sub>**"Results Worksheet: "Mold Summary All Shifts"**</sub>
<kbd>[image: Results Worksheet: "Mold Summary All Shifts"]</kbd>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mean can be calculated using the [AVERAGE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/average-function-047bac88-d466-426c-a32b-8f33eb960cf6)

The [FILTER function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) will return a subset of your data based on conditions.

Making these two changes should make it much simpler for you to review and extend your formula.

## 1.  "GHMP20 1" Only

<sup>**! ->** Asterisk **`*`** is equivalent to **`AND`**</sup>

###### 1a.   IFERROR : `""` If No Match

```
=IFERROR(
   AVERAGE(FILTER(N:N,(B:B=1)*
     (C:C="GHMP20 1"))),"")
```

###### 1b.   FILTER : `0` If No Match

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(N:N,(B:B=1)*
   (C:C="GHMP20 1"),0))
```

## 2.  "GHMP20 1" & "HMP20 1"

<sup>**! ->** Plus symbol **`+`** is equivalent to **`OR`**</sup>

###### 2a.   IFERROR : `""` If No Match

```
=IFERROR(
   AVERAGE(FILTER(N:N,(B:B=1)*
     ((C:C="GHMP20 1")+(C:C="HMP20 1"))),"")
```

###### 2b.   FILTER : `0` If No Match

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(N:N,(B:B=1)*
   ((C:C="GHMP20 1")+(C:C="HMP20 1")),0))
```